# Amazon AWS cannot connect to instance via ssh, connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new in amazon aws and I try to connect my instance via ssh from my ubuntu machine. Below my account configuration:
SecurityGroup:
[image]

RoutingTable:
[image]

Subnet:
[image]

Maybe there are missing some data but I'm not sure where and what I should add to get this working. I'm able to use aws cli to perform cli commands so I have access to my account via my secret key

Comment: Instance created in a public or private subnet?

Comment: Also, to what ip are you trying to connect?

Comment: Standard connectivity troubleshooting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: Thanks for answers, the problem was that I tried to connect to instance via private ip when it was attached to public subnet.